# Force http on single page with site wide https is in place

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, http, https, redirection

On my website, I have one page that loads content in iframe form other sources and hence cannot have an http connection. I have an SSL installed and have a site wide https forced on all urls. I am running Symfony 1.4 application and the rewrites and redirects at various level are:

VirtualHost Setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myserver.com
   ServerAlias www.myserver.com
   Redirect permanent / https://myserver.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver.com
  ServerAlias www.myserver.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/ssl/myserver.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ssl/myserver.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/ssl/cert.ca-bundle
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver/web
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory /var/www/myserver>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/var/www/myserver/web/images">
    LimitRequestBody 2147483647
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]  
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTPHOST}%{REQUESTURI} 

  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want that only this page /link-view/, should be on http. I tried modifying the .htaccess by adding these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} link-view
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But it does not work and shows 'too many redirects' on the page. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it. You've created a loop in yours, that's what the too many redirects means. Here you take the case of https off, not the page link-view, then redirect it to https. The second now is free to act only on link-view. Also, you want to be explicit about the path, is the URI yoursite.com/link-view? If so, you should make it so explicitly. ! means not. ^ means starts with. You're using rewritebase / so you don't need the starting /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^link-view
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^link-view
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

It's helpful to sometimes just think it through following the urls in yours:

```
# rule 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# rule 2
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} link-view
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Your first rule redirects everything http to https.

Then the page reloads, having been redirected. Then test 2 kicks in. https is on, having been redirected to https already. Say the url is link-view, that's correct, the third part is always true, so that means, the second rule will now redirect link-view to http, so the first rule now takes the page again, sees it's http, and turns it back into https, and so on, an infinite loop.